# pull_request_target Github Action not triggering

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I am creating a new GitHub Action workflow in my repository with the pull_request_target trigger on the closing of a pull request (to clean up allocated resources) from a branch to master. But it isn't triggering when I close the pull request (using the close pull request button in GitHub). I can't find what I'm doing wrong with my action

```yaml
name: Pull request closing workflow

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  target_test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: echo 
        run: |
         echo "HELLO WORLD!"
```

Comment: I just tried your workflow above and it works perfectly.

Comment: Is it a PR that's from inside the same repo or cross repo? The `Fork pull request workflows from outside collaborators` policy may be interfering with this.

Comment: This is on a PR from inside the same repository. Are there any repository settings or branch protection rules which could be interfering? We had a previous workflow that was running on pull_request trigger of type closed (and have existing workflows for push on master and pull_request opened, synchronize, reopened)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... It can happen when the pull request is closed by a GitHub Action though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. The pull_request_target trigger only runs from the master branch and I hadn't merged my PR yet, so it couldn't trigger. I merged the code and then it worked fine.